# Write the private key to the token

Tags: winapi, pkcs#11, cryptoapi

i use PKCS#11 to emulate token, i've a certificate in windows certificate store with "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate". i try to find WinAPI function which can read the private key of the certificate (which is either in the certificate store or on the hard drive in pfx format). How i can do this?
My function

```
static void ImportPrivateKey(const char* fileName, const char* password)
{
    HCERTSTORE  hSystemStore;

    //Open the certificate store to be searched
    if(hSystemStore = CertOpenStore(
      CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
      0,
      NULL,
      CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
      L"MY"))
        printf("Opened the MY system store. \n");
    else
        printf( "Could not open the MY system store.\n");

    PCCERT_CONTEXT  pDesiredCert = NULL;
    LPWSTR lpszCertSubject = L"7172gka"; // !!!!  Name of certificate to search 

    // Search certificate
    if(pDesiredCert=CertFindCertificateInStore(
      hSystemStore,
      MY_ENCODING_TYPE,
      0,
      CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
      lpszCertSubject ,
      pDesiredCert))
    {
        printf("The desired certificate was found. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not find the desired certificate.\n");
    }

    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO* pKeyInfo = NULL;

    if(!(CertGetCertificateContextProperty( 
      pDesiredCert, 
      CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, 
      NULL, 
      &dwSize))) 
    { 
        printf("Error getting key property.\n"); 
    }

    if(pKeyInfo) 
        free(pKeyInfo);

    pKeyInfo = (CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO*)malloc(dwSize);

    if(!pKeyInfo) 
    { 
        printf("Error allocating memory for pKeyInfo.\n"); 
    }

    if(!(CertGetCertificateContextProperty( 
      pDesiredCert, 
      CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, 
      pKeyInfo, 
      &dwSize)))
    {
        printf("The second call to the function failed\n");
    }

    printf("%s\n", pKeyInfo->pwszProvName);
    if(pKeyInfo->dwKeySpec == AT_SIGNATURE)
        printf("Ok!\n");
}
```

Comment: you need call `CertGetCertificateContextProperty` with `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` for get provider info and than export private key from provider container

Comment: @RbMm how can i export?
i update function

Comment: Could you share your use case of writing the private key to the token?